# WSTP broken by upgrade to 10.0.1?

Tags: bugs, mathlink-or-wstp, linux

**Bug introduced v10.0.1 and fixed in 10.0.2**

---

Everything was working fine with [WSTP](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/WSTPAPI.html) (the successor to MathLink) in 10.0.0. But I upgraded to 10.0.1 today and now I can't compile either my programs (I've changed nothing - the directories to the libraries are the same as before) or the example programs provided with Mathematica.

Running the makefile gives undefined references to every single WSTP function used in the program. For example, for the program `addtwo.c` (provided as an example in MMA), I get undefined references to `WSGetInteger`, `WSPutInteger`, `WSEvaluate` and many more.

Has anyone else encountered this problem? Is there something I need to change?

System: *Ubuntu 12.04, Mathematica 10.0.1.*

Comment: I've added a bug tag, based on @sakra's answer below that the shared libraries in Linux are broken, and that one must use the static libraries instead.

Comment: This may help you, but I'm not sure.
http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/67787/a-bug-fix-to-mathematica-10-0-1-0

Comment: This has been fixed as of version 10.0.2.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Under Linux the WSTP shared libraries that ship with Mathematica 10.0.1 for both 64 and 32 bit (`libWSTP64i4.so` and `libWSTP32i4.so`) appear to be broken. Link with the static versions `libWSTP64i4.a` or `libWSTP32i4.a` instead. The Windows and OS X versions are OK.

Comment: Perfect, all working fine now - thanks!