# A bug fix to mathematica 10.0.1.0

Tags: programming, mathlink-or-wstp, windows

There is a bug in the [Wolfram Symbolic Transfer Protocol](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/WSTPAPI.html) Development in C (Windows).

I described it in the next answer by myself, from which I summarize:

> One cannot successfully compile the `addtwo.c` demo in `C:\Program Files\Wolfram Research\Mathematica\10.0\SystemFiles\Links\WSTP\DeveloperKit\Windows\WSTPExamples\addtwo`, even if one follows the instructions in "WSTP Development in C (Windows)" strictly.

Question: Does anybody have a patch?

Well, I have one and I can post it here as an answer if somebody gives me a hint on how to do it.

BTW, is anybody interested in Mathematica related programming with DELPHI, I have done a bit of code porting, any suggestions on pascal style porting are welcomed.

Comment: I suppose you could post it to a place like GitHub and provide a link. Your description is pretty vague and hardly seems like a question for other users to answer.  (This is a Q&A site.)

Comment: @MichaelE2 But he can answer himself!

Comment: @belisarius The only (explicit) question is how to post an attachment.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Yeah, yeah, there :). I'll edit the question

Comment: seems related to http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/60445/1364

Comment: I added what I thought was the crux of the question. I think it is good to have a description of the problem in the question, so that users can see easily what it about.  Also I tagged it "Windows" for now.  If someone else knows the problem exists on other platforms and that Donald's patch fixes it, this could be changed.

Answer (score 3):

Wolfram has replaced MathLink with WSTP, but both their document and tool related to this are outofdated. Because of this bug, nobody could successfully compile the "addtwo.c" demo in "C:\Program Files\Wolfram Research\Mathematica\10.0\SystemFiles\Links\WSTP\DeveloperKit\Windows\WSTPExamples\addtwo", even if he followed the instruction in "WSTP Development in C (Windows)" strictly. The fixed document can be download from Baidu netdisk:[link](http://pan.baidu.com/s/1kT1K5mv) password: xiwn

Thanks for MichaelE2's suggestion. I should post this in Wolfram community [link](http://community.wolfram.com), but I never login the site successfully, so ...

Answer (score 3):

I did compile the addtwo example using CreateExecutable as follows:

```
examplesDir = 
  FileNameJoin[{$InstallationDirectory, "SystemFiles", "Links", 
        "WSTP", "DeveloperKit", $SystemID, "WSTPExamples", "addtwo"}];
files = FileNames["*", examplesDir]

compilerAdditionsDir = 
 FileNameJoin[{$InstallationDirectory, "SystemFiles", "Links", "WSTP",
        "DeveloperKit", $SystemID, "CompilerAdditions", "mldev64"}]

CCompilerDriver`CCompilerDriverBase`Private`$MprepExePath = 
 FileNameJoin[{compilerAdditionsDir, "bin", "wsprep.exe"}]

exe = CreateExecutable[files, "addtwo",
  "ShellCommandFunction" -> Print,
  "SystemLibraries" -> "wstp64i4m.lib",
  "SystemIncludeDirectories" -> 
       FileNameJoin[{compilerAdditionsDir, "include"}], 
  "SystemLibraryDirectories" -> 
       FileNameJoin[{compilerAdditionsDir, "lib"}]]
```