# Can't get the most basic WSTP demo (addtwo.c) to build and link. Help?

Tags: mathlink-or-wstp, external-calls

I am trying to use WSTP and started with the addtwo demo. I converted the template file to C using wsprep, then in Visual Studio 2013, added that, the addtwo.c file, the wstp libraries and the header file to the project. It compiled as a console app but would not link, reporting that it could not find main().

The error can be seen here:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Note, I'm not a windows guy! But it seems that you don't have configured your project correctly. `AddTwo` is a simple console application and as it looks, the project you created is not a console application. You can change that in the solution settings somewhere. Can you check that?

Comment: Please read *carefully* the instructions [here in the WSTP documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/WSTPDeveloperGuide-Windows.html#13917).

Comment: @halirutan addtwo is in fact *not* supposed to be a console application on Windows, but the fact that it complains about `_main` missing suggests that either the wrong source code is being compiled (not the Windows version of addtwo) or it's compiled with the wrong defines.  @Michael, also, as I said in an earlier comment, you need to include *one* version of the library, presumably i4 for Mma 10, not *all* versions.

Comment: Take a look here too: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/67787/12

Comment: @Szabolcs so is this a simple mistake (for someone who is interested and read WSTP documentation)?

Comment: @Kuba I don't think so.  I think no one uses MathLink regularly so it always takes some documentation browsing to get started on a new project.  Then this question is also on the intersection of MathLink, Windows programming and VisualStudio.  I don't know much about the latter two. It appears the OP is compiling as a console program (which is why the linker is looking for `_main`), while it should be compiled as a Windows GUI program instead.  How to do this in VisualStudio I have no idea.  When I do these things on Windows I still use command line, which I find more predictable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has been over a year since I asked this question and I have since gotten the demo code to compile and have built and deployed several WSTP projects of my own. I suspect that the key problem above is that I was trying to compile a console application rather than a Win32 application.

I also notice that in the Solution Explorer above I've included several unnecessary libraries. wstp32i4.lib should suffice. @Szabolcs had both of these things right at the time.