# Install[] of working WSTP executable hangs, Mathematica 10.1, linux

Tags: linux, mathlink-or-wstp

I am trying to use WSTP to link to the addtwo.c function example that comes with *Mathematica*. I have compiled addtwo successfully (took an effort) and if I run it in the command line I can connect it to *Mathematica* and use it. However running

```
Install["./addtwo"]
```

in *Mathematica* just hangs until I abort. The precompiled addtwo binary that comes with *Mathematica* does install fine.
Is there a way to find out more about why the `Install[]` fails?

I compiled using the (adapted) makefile which produces:

```
:~$ make addtwo
/usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica/10.1/SystemFiles/Links/WSTP/DeveloperKit/Linux-x86-64/CompilerAdditions/wsprep addtwo.tm -o addtwotm.c
gcc -c -I/usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica/10.1/SystemFiles/Links/WSTP/DeveloperKit/Linux-x86-64/CompilerAdditions addtwotm.c
gcc -c -I/usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica/10.1/SystemFiles/Links/WSTP/DeveloperKit/Linux-x86-64/CompilerAdditions addtwo.c
gcc -I/usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica/10.1/SystemFiles/Links/WSTP/DeveloperKit/Linux-x86-64/CompilerAdditions addtwotm.o addtwo.o -L/usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica/10.1/SystemFiles/Links/WSTP/DeveloperKit/Linux-x86-64/CompilerAdditions -lWSTP64i4 -lm -lpthread -lrt -lstdc++ -ldl -luuid -lWSTP64i4  -o addtwo
```

Note that addition of `-lWSTP64i4` didn't change anything, I tried it because of [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/60448/11163) which was already a bit desperate.

Could it be because of my gcc version? ( 4.6.3-1ubuntu5 )

Comment: You can try to set up the MathLink ("WSTP") connection manually to find out at which step it fails.  First run `addtwo` in a terminal.  It should give you a "Create link:" prompt.  Type the name of a link (you can make it up).  Let's say you chose the name "foo".  Now in Mathematica, do `link = LinkConnect["foo"]`, then finally `Install[link]`.  If all went well, `addtwo` will be "installed" now and ready to use.  Otherwise you'll find out at whcih step the failure happens.

Comment: I may be wrong about this, but I doubt it's your gcc version.  I tested compiling MathLink executables with gcc 4.6 and M 10.2 the other day.  It worked.

Comment: BTW just in case, try the MathLink version as well instead of WSTP.  It's the very same thing, just renamed.

Comment: See also [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/96572/wstp-hangs-up-in-mathematica-10-2/96595#96595) answer.

Comment: @Szabolcs Wow! Fast! I tried the two step version you suggested and it worked. Just doing it without running `addtwo` in a terminal doesn't. However I tried MathLink (I was not optimistic and a bit annoyed maybe...) but it works! I used the same makefile, just replaced the `WSTPLINKDIR`, the `WSTPLIB`, and set `WSPREP` to the `mprep` executable. So either the library or the preparation file is broken I guess.

Comment: @ilian I should have made it more explicit I guess that in my case running the executable outside of Mathematica and then linking via `Install["foo",LinkMode->Connect]` worked even with the WSTP settings.

Comment: @Szabolcs If you put an answer saying "use mathlink" I will accept it. There might be a bug somewhere in the WSTP stuff but if MathLink works that is a clean solution for me.

Comment: Are you sure it is not what @ilian is saying though?  The Mathematica launch script might modify `PATH` and `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, causing the `addtwo` executable not to find the WSTP shared library (while the MathLink one works because Mathematica it).  This is just a theory, of course.  Can you test it?  Either copy the shared libraries or check those environment variables from within Mathematica using `GetEnvironment`.

Comment: (Or rather use `SetEnvironment` to add the directory containing the WSTP libraries to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` *from within Mathematica*.)

Comment: @Szabolcs Ok that was it! @ilian Sorry for not reading that answer carefully enough. I admit I don't know too much about these things, but I thought the "static linking" via `-lWSTP64i4` during compilation would have taken care of that problem. It does not. And I am not even sure that what I did was static linking or whether that means what I thought it means. Anyway setting `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` within Mathematica worked with the WSTP version. Thank you for the help! So how do I give due credit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Summarizing the comments into an answer: this is really the same issue as in [WSTP hangs in Mathematica 10.2](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/96572/wstp-hangs-up-in-mathematica-10-2/96595#96595).

If using dynamic linking (`-lWSTP64i4` will pick up the `.so` library by default), then said shared library should be copied to a systemwide location or put on `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

The prebuilt examples do not exhibit this behavior because they are statically linked. The same can be accomplished by using `-L${LIBDIR} libWSTP64i4.a` in your link line.

If one uses the MathLink examples instead, they will work without additional requirements even if dynamically linked. The reason is that when *Mathematica* is started, it adds to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` the `$InstallationDirectory/SystemFiles/Libraries/$SystemID` directory, which has a copy of the corresponding MathLink libraries, `libML32i4.so` and `libML64i4.so`.

Comment: Thanks for putting up an answer! Maybe add that just using MathLink instead of WSTP also solves the problem? For amateurs like me it seems like the easiest solution in hindsight. Of course sooner or later getting to grips with dynamic and static linking etc. will probably be necessary. But maybe someone just needs the whole linking thing once for one C function and then there is no need to get into compiling details.

Comment: I actually have the directory with `-lWSTP64i4` on my `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` (at least in .bashrc which might not be "global"?) but that is not enough to make it work. So I think it should be mentioned that `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` should be set inside Mathematica. Or somewhere where Mathematica is affected wherever that may be...

Comment: @tortortor Added a note about MathLink. Regarding `.bashrc`, the setting there would work, provided *Mathematica* is actually started from a shell that has this variable set. But in the case when the parent process is different, you would need to set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` in an appropriate way for your OS, so it can be inherited properly.

Comment: Perhaps `~/.profile` is a good place for a persistent setting. In any case, how environment variables work is not really a *Mathematica* issue, though `SetEnvironment` is convenient to use within a *Mathematica* session.