# Install hangs for precompiled Cuba integration executable

Tags: mathlink-or-wstp

I am trying to use the [Cuba integration package](http://www.feynarts.de/cuba/) in *Mathematica* 10.2 on a Windows 10 machine. However, having downloaded the supplied Vegas.exe MathLink executable, when I try running `Install["Vegas.exe"]`, *Mathematica* just hangs.

As far as I understand what the website says, the executable should be statically linked, thus I am not sure the issue is the same as in other `Install` hang questions on this site. However I am not very well versed in compilation details, so I might of course be wrong.

I run everything inside a cygwin-terminal.

When executing the Vegas.exe I do not get a "make link" prompt, as I understand I should from [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/101521/install-of-working-wstp-executable-hangs-mathematica-10-1-linux), so I guess that indicates that something is wrong?

Any tips would be welcome.

Comment: Have you contacted the package author?